# I want to call a reduce with a list that contains longs an ints in python

Tags: python, int, long-integer, reduce

I am trying to call a reduce on a list that contains ints and longs. For example,

```
reduce( int.__mul__, [ 231212312412L, 3 ], 1 )
```

but I get an unimplemented error. and when I replace the int's mul method with the long's mul method it complains that it is getting an int. Must I map them all to a long first? like this.

```
reduce( long.__mul__, map( long, [ 12312412314L, 5 ] ), 1L )
```

Comment: You also don't need to specify an initial value, it will take the first two items from the sequence to start.

Comment: just make a damn `for` loop. It's faster and readable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
>>> from operator import mul
>>> reduce( mul, map( long, [ 12312412314L, 5 ] ), 1 )
61562061570L
>>> reduce( mul, [ 231212312412L, 3 ], 1 )
693636937236L
>>>
```

operator has:

```
'abs',
 'add',
 'and_',
 'attrgetter',
 'concat',
 'contains',
 'countOf',
 'delitem',
 'delslice',
 'div',
 'eq',
 'floordiv',
 'ge',
 'getitem',
 'getslice',
 'gt',
 'iadd',
 'iand',
 'iconcat',
 'idiv',
 'ifloordiv',
 'ilshift',
 'imod',
 'imul',
 'index',
 'indexOf',
 'inv',
 'invert',
 'ior',
 'ipow',
 'irepeat',
 'irshift',
 'isCallable',
 'isMappingType',
 'isNumberType',
 'isSequenceType',
 'is_',
 'is_not',
 'isub',
 'itemgetter',
 'itruediv',
 'ixor',
 'le',
 'lshift',
 'lt',
 'methodcaller',
 'mod',
 'mul',
 'ne',
 'neg',
 'not_',
 'or_',
 'pos',
 'pow',
 'repeat',
 'rshift',
 'sequenceIncludes',
 'setitem',
 'setslice',
 'sub',
 'truediv',
 'truth',
 'xor'
```

Answer (score 5):

`int.__mul__` can only multiply two integers, likewise, `long.__mul__` two longs. But the normal `*` operator will automatically handle different numerical types for you, so what you can do is simply use a lambda that passes off the work to '*':

```
reduce( lambda x,y: x*y, [ 231212312412L, 3 ], 1 )
```

Or yes, use `operator.mul` but remember to import it first! (That'd probably be faster, actually)

Answer (score 3):

You want [`operator.mul`](http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html#operator.mul).

Answer (score 2):

you don't need that fancy `reduce`.

```
total = 1
for x in your_list:
     total *= x
```

That's much more readable and faster